# Yukel's Sieve - Factorization of Numbers into a Square Sieve

Tags: keys, prime-numbers, factoring

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liTTGeitpGQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nOwgiweyqc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGwFsOG27DQ

I came across these videos explaining a pattern that is found in numbers over $27,000^2 = 729,000,000$.

The author claims that because he found the solution for prime numbers, that all current security keys will become obsolete:

"Interference Pattern over 30 revealed. Basis for New Factorization and Prime Finding Algorithm. 64 sets of two 900 by 900  modulo and remainder grids are all you need to find the factors to any number. The pattern repeats every 27000 or over a surface of 30^6"

"Basically all you need to find all the factors of every number are 64 grids of 900by900"

The author basically mapped the ideas expressed in this video, onto a plane: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0CL7bv-UDk

From what I understand, this forms a fractal of prime numbers.

Can anyone view and verify his claims?
I am not a security / cryptography expert, however I would like to find out more.

Thank you.

The Author's Channel:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfLDFyvPLNv2M8mHOMjDxuw/videos?view=0&sort=dd&shelf_id=0

Comment: Frankly, this sounds like nonsense [snake oil, whatever]. There is no need to check these non-scientific claims due to many reasons, I will state just a few:

If these were real, this person would be breaking RSA making millions instead of publishing them. Or if he wasn't interested in money, he'd submit a scientific paper with proofs and gain fame.

When there are such simple patterns in primes, they occur very rarely, with thinning probability as the interval [1,n] we look at increases. 

The question may well be off-topic as well, in terms of evaluating security claims, designs etc.

Comment: Finding a pattern that repeats with period $30^6<2^{30}$ reduces the entropy of an unknown prime factor of let's say 1024 bit by at most 30 bits. As about every 700th 1024-bit number is prime, Mr. Yukel has still a long way to go before I'd get scared of his attacks on RSA.